# With the requests library, is it possible to get GitHub repository information?

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I am making a program that I want to be able to natively update when the GitHub repository is updated. Is there any way I can be able to do this with python? I have looked it but nothing has helped. I would need this to work on other PC's than my own. Thank you!

Comment: Just run `git pull`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some information from a [`GitHub`](https://github.com/) repository that you own, a better idea is to download [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) or [`GitHub Desktop`](https://desktop.github.com/) to manage your clone easily.

In particular, if you want to update your local `clone` with the commits `push`ed to the remote repository, you just have to run the command `git pull`.

---

You just have to open `Git Bash`, go to your clone repository's path, and write `git pull`.

```
user@DESKTOP-D9F15J2 MINGW64 /d/C++/Labirint (main)
$ git pull
```

Comment: FLAK-ZOSO, other people could use it on their computers, the repository is public.

Comment: Git works on other's computers for sure 

Comment: No, I mean they may not have git/Github Desktop on their computers.

Comment: So you want to create an alternative to Git with Python? Bad idea.

Comment: No, I want to use the requests module to get GitHub repository.

Comment: So you want to clone a GitHub repository via Python? And keep it updated? I'm afraid it's not such an easy thing to do, and git is already existing and does exactly the same thing the fastest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no way the third party can use Git directly and you really want to stick to Python, maybe you should try [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython#gitpython). You can write a reoccuring script that [pulls](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes) the repo every now and then.

Comment: This isn't a pure Python request solution but for sure it's similar to what the OP was looking for. Anyway thanks, I found the link useful, +1